# Correct way to write nested queries within from clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

First of all I am sorry if this is a dumb question. I am terribly confused right now and I could not find any proper documentation regarding my doubts.

> So here is a `table` namely `station` with following description.

```
+--------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city   | varchar(21)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state  | varchar(21)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lat_n  | decimal(15,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| long_w | decimal(15,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

> My objective is to find the `median` of `lat_n`. For this I have written following query[incomplete yet] which is giving me `error`,

```
set @id := 0;
select id , round(lat,4) as r, median 
from (
    (select @id := @id +1 as `id`,lat_n as lat , @middle:=@middle as median from station) as a,
    (select @middle:=floor((count(*)+1)/2) from station) as c order by lat_n
)as b
group by id,r,median 
having id = median
```

I am struggling with the nested queries here within the `from` clause mostly because of the `parenthesis` and the `comma` before the second `select` inside `from` clause. What I want to understand truly are the following:

- What is the meaning of multiple `sub queries` inside `from` clause. For example I have two `select` queries inside `from` clause now. So what do they represent?
- How would I add one more `select` there?
- Correct way to use the `parenthesis` and `commas` to include all the `select` queries there like in my code[But it is giving error].

> [Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa8acd/1)
>
> Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want someone to explain you "your" code?

Comment: Nope. I want to know the correct way to write the code inside the `from` clause.

Comment: Here is a fix without syntax errors: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa8acd/9 - But i don't know what it's doing.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks ! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why use this ugly query? Why variables? Why subselects? Do you know it returns one id, although many could have the median lat_n value? That the id is the median value, not an id whose lat_n is the median value? That a subselect ORDER BY without LIMIT does nothing? Do you know it can be simpler? Assuming you know what a select statement does, why don't you know what each subexpression is doing? Please edit your question to say what you are you trying to accomplish, why you have this query, what you think it does & what particular subexpression is the 1st you can't understand.